# Backend of paypal incontext Example at Plunker

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

In one of the examples of Paypal docs at Plunker for in-context type payments, the url is given but there is no documentation of what is inside that backend. Can someone please help.

```
<div class="row product">
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <h3>Toy Story Jessie T-Shirt</h3>
              <p>
              <a href="http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/aries.cgi?live=1&returnurl=http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/return.htm&cancelurl=http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/cancel.htm" id="t1" class="checkout">
                  <img class="paypal-button-hidden" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_FR/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" alt="Check out with PayPal" />
              </a>
              </p>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the Example:http://plnkr.co/edit/UhNka4VaaRRGY1TK32LE?p=preview
Here is the URL: http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/aries.cgi?live=1&returnurl=http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/return.htm&cancelurl=http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/cancel.htm

Answer (score 7):

**HTML:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    </head>
    <body>
     <form id="myContainer" method="post" action="ec_call.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">

    </form>
         <script>
            window.paypalCheckoutReady = function() {
                paypal.checkout.setup('S4X5XW328WAYY', {
                    container: 'myContainer', 
                    environment: 'sandbox'
                    // button: 'incontext_id'

                });

            }

        </script>
    </body>
<script src="//www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async></script>
</html>
```

Now, inside `ec_call.php` you will need to run your SetExpresscheckout [API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) call and in that return URL just do Doexpresscheckout [API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) call.
That's it.

Also you can download the PHP sample [code](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7kGwoCqfDv7VkRlMVdoS1B0cXM&usp=sharing) .

Comment: @kleopatra I was in the process of updating :P Done that now.

Comment: @techycommerce I went to your site and followed your instructions to the letter. (at least I think I did.) My problem is that the modal window opens, starts to load and then closes and redirects my web site to PayPal. Defeating the point of using In-context. Is there a parameter I'm missing?

Comment: The "ec_call.php" MUST redirect to the PayPal page, you can use `header('Location: <url>);`

Comment: It seems the link to your sample demo doesn't work anymore. Is it available elsewhere?

Comment: @MarcS82 added the download link
its here 
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7kGwoCqfDv7VkRlMVdoS1B0cXM&usp=sharing